# How does one find the Fourier coefficients of a piecewise continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How does one find the Fourier coefficients of the following functions $f:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

1. $f(t)=t$ for $-\pi < t < \pi$ and $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)=0$
2. $f(t)=-1$ for $-\pi < t < 0$, $f(t)=0$ for $t=-\pi,0,\pi$ and $f(t)=1$ for $0<t<\pi$ , $2\pi$ periodically extended to functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

What I have tried:

The coefficients for a function defined on $-\pi < x <  \pi$   :$$a_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)dx ; $$ $$b_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(kx)dx$$$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x) dx $$

i think $$a_k+ib_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{ikx}dx$$

for 1) : $\int x \cos(kx) dx$= $$\frac{1}{k}\sin(kx)x -\frac{1}{k} \int \sin(kx)dx = \frac{1}{k}(x\sin(kx)+\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2})$$  so: $$ a_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} x\cos(kx)dx = \frac{(k\pi \sin(k\pi))+ \cos(k \pi) + k\pi \sin(-k\pi)-\cos(-k\pi)}{k^2}=0  $$

for $$\int x \sin(kx)dx = \frac{-kx\cos(kx)+\sin(kx)}{k^2} $$ : $$\Rightarrow b_k=  \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x \sin(kx)dx = \frac{(-k \pi \cos(k\pi)+\sin(k \pi) - (k\pi \cos(kx)+\sin(-k\pi)}{\pi k^2}) = \frac{2 \sin (\pi k)-2k\pi \cos(kx)}{\pi k^2}$$

and $a_0= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x dx =  0$

is this correct for 1) ?

And, how does one find the Fourier coefficients of a piecewise given function? Take the coefficients for each boundary and sum them up e.g. : 
$$a_0 = \int_{-\pi}^{0}-1 dx + \int_{0}^{\pi}1 dx $$

and analogous for $a_k$, $b_k$ ?

Comment: restart using the complex Fourier series and retreat back to $a_k$ and $b_k$ later.

Comment: Since $x\cos (kx)$ is odd, its integral over $[-\pi,\pi]$ is $0$. No need to compute. For your $b_k$, use $\cos (k\pi)=(-1)^k$ and $\sin(k\pi)=0$.

Comment: what about piecewise defined functions? How does one find the coefficients for such  functions?